# Rolling Sum for Last 12 Months in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, date-arithmetic, lateral-join

I'm trying to get the rolling sum for the past 12 months (Oct 2019-Sept 2020, etc.)> So far, I figured out to get the current year total (which I also want), however, I'm stuck on a legit 12 month rolling sum.

```
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, ENTRY_DATE), 0) AS Payout_Month, SUM(PRINCIPAL_AMT) Payout_amt, 
SUM(SUM(PRINCIPAL_AMT)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(ENTRY_DATE) ORDER BY MIN(ENTRY_DATE)) as YearRollingSum,
SUM(SUM(PRINCIPAL_AMT)) OVER (PARTITION BY Year(ENTRY_DATE)
                  ORDER BY MIN(ENTRY_DATE)
                  ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                 )  AS TwelveMonthRollingSum
FROM ACCOUNTHISTORY
WHERE LEFT(TOKEN_STRING, 4) LIKE '%Py%'
AND FOCUS_TELLER_ID = 6056
AND PRINCIPAL_AMT > 0 AND PRINCIPAL_AMT < 25
AND ENTRY_DATE >= '01/01/2019'
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, ENTRY_DATE), 0), YEAR(ENTRY_DATE) 
Order BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, ENTRY_DATE), 0)
```

here's what my current output looks like

```
Payout_Month            Payout_amt  YearRollingSum  TwelveMonthRollingSum
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 5696.50     5696.50            NULL
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 11205.60    16902.10          5696.50
2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 23341.50    40243.60          16902.10
2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 25592.80    65836.40          40243.60
2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 28148.30    93984.70          65836.40
2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 27190.90    121175.60         93984.70
2019-07-01 00:00:00.000 25079.80    146255.40         121175.60
2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 30206.90    176462.30         146255.40
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000 28000.80    204463.10         176462.30
2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 29076.60    233539.70         204463.10
2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 29001.30    262541.00         233539.70
2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 28366.00    290907.00         262541.00
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 32062.40    32062.40          NULL
2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 28526.70    60589.10          32062.40
2020-03-01 00:00:00.000 29056.50    89645.60          60589.10
2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 28016.00    117661.60         89645.60
2020-05-01 00:00:00.000 25173.30    142834.90         117661.60
2020-06-01 00:00:00.000 27646.10    170481.00         142834.90
2020-07-01 00:00:00.000 36083.70    206564.70         170481.00
2020-08-01 00:00:00.000 34872.20    241436.90         206564.70
2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 35727.10    277164.00         241436.90
2020-10-01 00:00:00.000 34030.80    311194.80          277164.00
```

AS you can see, it resets at the beginning of the year for the last column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to remove the `partition by` clause from the rolling 12 month sum. I would also suggest a few optimizations to the query:

```
select 
    x.payout_month, 
    sum(ah.principal_amt) payout_amt, 
    sum(sum(ah.principal_amt)) over (
        partition by year(x.payout_month) 
        order by x.payout_month
    ) as yearrollingsum,
    sum(sum(ah.principal_amt)) over (
        order by x.payout_month
        rows between 12 preceding and 1 preceding
    )  as twelvemonthrollingsum
from accounthistory ah
cross apply (values (datefromparts(year(ah.entry_date), month(entry_date), 1))) x(ah.payout_month)
where 
    left(ah.token_string, 4) like '%py%'
    and ah.focus_teller_id = 6056
    and ah.principal_amt > 0 and principal_amt < 25
    and ah.entry_date >= '20190101'
group by x.payout_month
order by x.payout_month
```

The main change is that the `payout_month` is computed only once, in a lateral join, using `datefromparts()`. You can then use it all over the query, and consistently in the `order by` clauses of the window functions.

Note that your strategy will fail to produce a proper results if you ever have a month without any sale (the `rows` clause of the window function will spread over the preceding month, which is not what you want). If that's something that may happen, then an alternative is a subquery, or another lateral join.